# Why can a differential that goes after the integrand and a differential in the denominator of a derivative inside the integrand "cancel out"?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was watching a [video on the Separation of Variables method for solving ODEs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Y-frhf-1Zk&list=PLHXZ9OQGMqxde-SlgmWlCmNHroIWtujBw&index=3).

In minute 2:10, after having integrating both sides of the equation with respect to $dt$ we have
$$
\int\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dt} dt = \int k dt
$$
Then, the term $\dfrac{dy}{dt}dt$ on the left side is substituted by $dy$. If differentials are not treated like numbers which cancel out when multiplying and dividing and the $dt$ after the integrand is not multiplying by the integrand but instead indicating with respect to which variable we are integrating it, what justifies this step?

Comment: This is a standard [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), aka change of variables or reverse chain rule.